# Is there a way to see if the value of a textfield is equal to a value in a dictionary in Swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm making a simple search engine in xcode. It is supposed to work by seeing if the text in a textfield is equal to a value in a dictionary, and if so, do an action, like this:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var SearchField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var SearchButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var Result1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var Result2: UILabel!
    var possibleResults = ["Daniel":"www.example.com", "Bob":"www.asdf.com"]


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    }
    //if Go button is pressed
    @IBAction func SearchButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        //if Search field is equal to a value in possibleResults
        if SearchField is equal to a value in possibleResults {
            //makes result1 say hi
            self.Result1.text = "Hi"
        } else {
            self.Result1.text = "No Results"
        }
    }

}
```

Also, keep in mind I am pretty new to Swift, so simple and direct answers would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unwrap the text and check the result in one line, like following:

```
if let text = SearchField.text, result = possibleResults[text] {
    print(result)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
if possibleResults[SearchField.text ?? ""] != nil {
  // ...
}
```

or

```
if let _ = possibleResults[SearchField.text ?? ""] {
  // ...
}
```

if you do not need value that you get from dictionary.

If you will use value from dictionary then replace underscore with variable name:

```
if let value = possibleResults[SearchField.text ?? ""] {
  // ...
}
```